# Does adding a Swift enum case require a major semver version update?

Tags: swift, semantic-versioning

Unlike many languages, Swift's `switch` must be exhaustive, so if I have:

```
enum Enumeration
{
    case A
    case B
}
```

Then this code is invalid:

```
switch enumeration
{
case .A:
    break
}
```

However, these are valid:

```
switch enumeration
{
case .A:
    break
case .B:
    break
}

switch enumeration
{
case .A:
    break
default:
    break
}
```

If I later add `case C` to `Enumeration`, the first valid code is will now producer a compiler error. The second one is valid, since it uses `default:`, which will catch `.C`.

If I am complying to semver for `carthage` (or Swift Package Manager) support, must I increment the major version for this?

An extension of this extends to Objective-C (and implicitly C). Since C enumerations are supported in Swift as Swift enumerations, this would also apply to an Objective-C or C framework intended to be *used* in Swift. I'm not sure how to solve this, because those languages have no such restriction (just a warning, if your compiler's good).

Comment: (I believe the answer is "yes", but want confirmation)

Comment: You don't need default because Swift's type inference. Since Swift can infer the type of your enumeration it knows that you're enum has two cases and that your Switch is indeed exhaustive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer:** Adding new case to public enum in Swift is breaking change.

### Reasoning

The semantic versioning is not related to some language feature, it's about you API stability.
The Semantic version consist of main 3 parts (1.0.1):

- **Major** - MUST be incremented if any ***backwards incompatible*** changes are introduced to the public API
- **Minor** - MUST be incremented if new, ***backwards compatible*** functionality is introduced to the public API
- **Path** - MUST be incremented if only ***backwards compatible bug fixes*** are introduced

### Example:

Let's say you have a framework that contains this enum declaration:

```
//Framework
public enum Enumeration {
    case A
    case B
}
```

Here is an app that uses that framework

```
//App 
let en = Enumeration.A
switch en {
    case .A: print("A")
    case .B: print("B")
}
```

**Add Changes**
Now lets do some changes to the framework and see that's happen.
Let's add a new case to the enum.

```
//Framework
public enum Enumeration {
    case A
    case B
    case C
}
```

The `Enumeration` is a public API, it's visible to outside world. It means we have change our API. It has to be Major or Minor update, patch is when API is not changed.

If you try to compile and app, it will fail, because `switch` must be exhaustive in Swift.
[image]

So we have made breaking API change, and we have to increase Major version. 1.0.1 -> 2.0.0

## Important Note!

This issue will be handled in Swift 3.
Here is a response about this issue from Apple team.

[image]

> This will be handled as part of the resilience model. Public enums will not be exhaustively matchable outside their module.